# JcomboBox devuelve Null Pointer Excepcion

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

estoy realizando un proyecto para envio de encomiendas en Java y estoy teniendo un inconveniente para cargar unos combobox con datos traidos de una base de datos. 
En el stack trace me esta devolviendo como error lo que se puede apreciar en la imagen, y segun lo que pude observar la linea 239 a la que se hace referencia es cuando intento agregar un elemento en el combobox, lo cual me devuelve como resultado Null. 
Desde ya, quien tenga la amabilidad de ayudarme le estare agradecido. 
Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mi codigo para llenar el combobox, lo tengo en una clase aparte llamada UsuarioDAO

```
    public void usuarios_combo(JComboBox cbox_usuarios){
    try {

        String sql = "SELECT usu_ci FROM usuarios";
        Connection conn = this.getConexion();
        PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst1.setQueryTimeout(5);
        ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();

        while ((rs != null) && (rs.next())) {

            String ci = rs.getString(1);
            cbox_usuarios.addItem(ci);
        }

        pst1.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Names : " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        

}
```

Luego en la presentacion (el formulario donde muestro las encomiendas) tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class ListarEncomiendasAdmin extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtEstado;
    private JTextField txtOrigen;
    private JTextField txtDestino;
    private static JTable tblEncomiendas;
    private static EncomiendasDAO eDAO = new EncomiendasDAO();
    private static Object[][] dtEncomienda;
    private static JComboBox cmbRemitente;
    private static JComboBox cmbDestinatario;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UsuarioDAO uDAO = new UsuarioDAO(); 
                try {
                    ListarEncomiendasAdmin frame = new ListarEncomiendasAdmin();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    Actualizar_Tabla();
                    uDAO.usuarios_combo(cmbRemitente);
                    uDAO.usuarios_combo(cmbDestinatario);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿ Podrías especificar cual es la linea 239 donde te da el error ?

Comment: Hola, es en la linea que dice cbox_usuarios.addItem(ci);

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer he visto tu error en tu código. El error lo que quiere decirte es que no estas instanciando el el objeto **cmbRemitente**, tampoco el objeto **cmbUsuarios**. Por lo tanto el combo Box nunca esta inicializado por ende no puede cargar los elementos que quieres agregarle.

Te recomiendo que retornes un JComboBox de la siguiente manera:

```
public JComboBox usuarios_combo(){
JComboBox cbox_usuarios = new JComboBox();
try {

    String sql = "SELECT usu_ci FROM usuarios";
    Connection conn = this.getConexion();
    PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst1.setQueryTimeout(5);
    ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();

    while ((rs != null) && (rs.next())) {

        String ci = rs.getString(1);
        cbox_usuarios.addItem(ci);
    }

    pst1.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();

}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Names : " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}        
return cbox_usuarios;
```

Ahora desde tu clase **ListarEncomiendasAdmin** deberas igualar tu comboBox al del método que modificaste. Esto de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ListarEncomiendasAdmin extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtEstado;
private JTextField txtOrigen;
private JTextField txtDestino;
private static JTable tblEncomiendas;
private static EncomiendasDAO eDAO = new EncomiendasDAO();
private static Object[][] dtEncomienda;
private static JComboBox cmbRemitente;
private static JComboBox cmbDestinatario;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UsuarioDAO uDAO = new UsuarioDAO(); 
            try {
                cmbRemitente = new JComboBox();
                cmbDestinatario = new JComboBox();
                ListarEncomiendasAdmin frame = new ListarEncomiendasAdmin();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                Actualizar_Tabla();
                cmbRemitente = uDAO.usuarios_combo();
                cmbDestinatario = uDAO.usuarios_combo();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

De esta manera ya has inicializado tus ComnoBox, una vez inicializados los igualas al cbox_usuarios (método que mandas llamar), de esta manera se igualaran los items de cbox_usuarios a cmbRemitente y cmbDestinatario. 
Espero te haya funcionado. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, probe tu solucion y ahora estoy obteniendo como error SQLNonTransientException. De lo que pude ver en el debug, me trae los datos de la base de datos, itera correctamente pero al abrir el formulario, me muestra ese error y los combobox aparecen vacios